# How to open .url shortcuts (from Windows) on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, shortcuts, opera, url

I have Dropbox shared with Windows PC's which contain some .url internet shortcuts.  These do not open in Lubuntu.  How can I open these from Lubuntu?  Using the Opera browser on all platforms.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was [this trick](https://saidulhassan.com/open-url-files-in-linux-mint-ubuntu-1029) by Saidul Hassan, with some minor modifications.

*EDIT: I had to change this slightly to handle URL's with an '=' symbol in them.*

*EDIT2: Also adopted to use shortcuts with bracket characters in them, thanks to Kound.*

1. Right-click one of the .url files in Lubuntu file manager and go to `Open With...` or `Properties` --> `Open With` and choose `Custom Command Line`.
2. Enter this as the terminal command, substituting `opera` for the browser of your choice:

   ```
    bash -c "cat %f | grep -e 'URL\([[].*[]]\)\{0,1\}=' | cut -d= -f 2| xargs opera &"
   ```
3. Do NOT check "Execute in terminal emulator."
4. You must give it an Application Name at bottom.
5. Check the box for `Set selected application as default`.

An example should look like the following:

[image: How to open .url files in Lubuntu]

Now double-clicking .url files should open them as a new tab in the chosen browser.

Note: If you end up with more than three "Open With" associations to a file type, things may start behaving strangely.  To remove these extra associations, look in `/home/you/.local/share/applications` for some duplicated .desktop files and remove them.

Comment: Some URL files have a different URL format, something like `URL[$e]=`. You have to adopt the `grep` and `cut` command like this to have it also working:
`bash -c "cat %f | grep -e 'URL\([[].*[]]\)\{0,1\}=' | cut -d= -f 2| xargs opera &"`

Comment: Nice! However, `cat <file> | grep` mostly means a [useless use of cat](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/useless-use-of-cat/). Have you tried with `%f` directly used as the last argument of `grep`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a script and open the .url with it.

I have used these two scripts

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -h -s --color=never '^URL=' "$@" | cut -d'=' -f2- | xargs /snap/bin/chromium &
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

sed 's/^BASEURL=/URL=/' "$1" | grep -m 1 '^URL=' | sed 's/^URL=//' | sed 's/\r//' | xargs xdg-open
```

See which one works for you

Comment: works second one ubuntu 22.04